# My website is loading two different page content when it should be the same HTML file

Tags: html, css

The title says it all roughly...

When you access my site via [www.mjgibson.ca](http://www.mjgibson.ca) it loads a slightly different html file from going to [www.mjgibson.ca/index.html](http://www.mjgibson.ca/index.html)

I don't understand how they could be different though because its just one HTML file?

Hopefully one of you have encountered this before because I've been googling this question and can't seem to find someone experiencing this!

Comment: It depends on your hosting. For first url it may be set to access `index.php` (or something else like `site.html`) instead of `index.html`. In second url you are telling it to access `index.html` so this may be your problem.

Comment: This is 404 page, if any of the link not found on the website, then it shows 404 page. Probably your website is in pHp thats why .html file not shown

Comment: Have you checked your domain etc set up in your hosting admin panel (however that is accessed). It looks as though www.mgibson.ca is set to pick up a different file.

Comment: Is there actually an `index.html` file in your top-level folder? Be aware that it is probably case-sensitive.